# React Native native base Picker inside item not aligning right

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm trying to use a Picker inside my CardItem in the Right side. The picker is displayed correct in the right side, but its value is align to the Left (image below). Why is it happening?

[image]

```
<CardItem cardBody>
    <Left>
         <Entypo name="address" />
         <Text>State:</Text>
    </Left>
    <Right>
        <Item>
            <Picker
               mode="dropdown"
               iosHeader="Select State"
               placeholder="States"
               iosIcon={<Icon name="arrow-down" />}
               selectedValue={CurrentState}
               textStyle={{ color: '#C0C0C0' }}
               onValueChange={(text) => this.onChangeText(text, 'CurrentState')}
        >
            {Object.keys(localStates).map((key) => {
              return (
                  <Picker.Item
                     label={localStates[key]}
                     value={key}
                     key={key}
                   />
               );
             })}
           </Picker>
       </Item>
    </Right>
</CardItem>
```

`localStates` is just a key value const with the states.

Comment: If not  you can try remove `<Left>`

Comment: Still the same issue. It just works if I set a width for the picker style. However, is it fine to set width since phones have different sizes?

Comment: Set to percent, not absolute. ex) `width: "50%"`

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work. Doesn't matter how many percent I set, it still like the picture I posted.

Answer (score 0):

**I had similar issue when I worked on RTL layout. Add below style to res/values/styles.xml file. This will align picker items right in your app and apples, but globally Hope this will shed some light on**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- 
        ... existing styles
        --->
        <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItem</item>
 </style>
```

Then define your styles below

```
<style name="SpinnerItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
   <item name="android:textAlignment">gravity</item>
   <item name="android:gravity">right</item>
</style>
<style name="SpinnerDropDownItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
   <item name="android:textAlignment">gravity</item>
   <item name="android:gravity">right</item>
   <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
</style>
```

If you want to align based on RTL layout (eg. Arabic language) Then use below code

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- 
        ... existing styles
        --->
        <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItem</item>
 </style>
```

Then define your styles below

```
<style name="SpinnerItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
   <item name="android:textAlignment">gravity</item>
   <item name="android:gravity">start</item>
</style>
<style name="SpinnerDropDownItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
   <item name="android:textAlignment">gravity</item>
   <item name="android:gravity">start</item>
   <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
</style>
```